# I want to retrieve data from 4 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to retrieve data from 4 tables. `Patient` table has `id` as PK which is the foreign key in other three tables `ett`, `phar` and `ssc`. Where a patient lie in only one category. i.e patient id pt1 exists in either of the 3 tables. now I want to retrieve patient info along with its associated category.

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Patient p
INNER JOIN ETT t 
ON p.Patient_ID = t.Patient_ID  || INNER JOIN Pharmacological ph 
ON p.Patient_ID = ph.Patient_ID
```

I used `OR` clause because I want only 1 inner join executing at one time. but its not giving me results, any suggestions??

Comment: by that you mean, the ID of the patient may only exist in one of the tables in `ett`, `phar`, `ssc`?

Comment: which table you need to join with Patinet and which case?

Answer (score 2):

> ....Patient table has ID as PK which is the foreign key in other three
>   tables name: *ett*, *phar* and *ssc* where **a patient lie in only one
>   category**. Example, ***patient id pt1 exists in either of the 3 tables***.

Based on your statement, you can join all the tables in table `Patient` using `LEFT JOIN` since a record can only exist on one table. The query below uses `COALESCE` which returns the first *non-null* value with int the list.

The only thing you need is to manually specify the column names that you want to be shown on the list as shown below.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(t.colA, p.ColA, s.ColA) ColA, 
        COALESCE(t.colB, p.ColB, s.ColB) ColB,
        COALESCE(t.colN, p.ColN, s.ColN) ColN
FROM    Patient a
        LEFT JOIN ETT t
            ON a.Patient_ID = t.Patient_ID
        LEFT JOIN Phar p
            ON a.Patient_ID = p.Patient_ID
        LEFT JOIN SSC s
            ON a.Patient_ID = s.Patient_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

For or - do not ise ||, use "or"
You cannot join with or, you need re-format your query.